# Add a duration in time in php

Tags: php, datetime

My start time is 08:15 AM.
I want to add a duration of 01:00(1hr) in my start time so that final time comes to be 09:15 AM. How to do this?

Duration and start time can vary. And duration will only be in format 00:30, 01:00, 01:15...

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where is the code? On what should we make changes? Or do you want US to make it from scratch so you can copy-paste it? It doesn't work this way ;)

Comment: Explode `HH:MM` format to hours and minutes, calculate total number of minutes, and add minutes to your time.

Answer (score 3):

try this -

```
$time = "08:15 AM";
$date = date("h:i A", strtotime($time." + 1 hour"));
```

or if you want to add minutes then -

```
$time = "08:15 AM";
$date = date("h:i A", strtotime($time." + 90 minutes"));
```

Comment: How does this work, if start time is `08:15 AM`, and not current time like in your answer?

Comment: Great:) Also he is adding `HH:MM` format, so this will not work `+ 01:30 hour`. [demo](https://eval.in/211365)

Comment: yes i am adding in HH:MM  format, so i think need to calculate total minutes and then will add in it

Comment: thes you have to calculate it.

Comment: @user3541020: you have a demo in 3rd comment on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
date('H:i', strtotime('+30 minutes'));
```

Comment: How does this work, if start time is `08:15 AM`, and not current time like in your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Here's your solution:

if you're just using the current time,

```
$date = date('h:i:s A', time()+3600);
```

And if your are using `strtotime()`, it gives you a number back that represents a time in seconds. To increment it, add the corresponding number of seconds you want to add.

In that case write this line:

```
$today = time(); // or give your time here that is 08:15
$date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($today)+36000); // $today is today date
```